# Input string test with a regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to test a input string of format **AWT=10:15;**, based on this regex that I wrote: `(([AWT]\w\S=)?(\d{0,9}:)?(\d{0,9});)`.

Problem 1: I am receiving this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` when I try to match the string with the regex.

Problem 2: The string seems to come off as valid even after I enter this: **AWT=10:15;12** which shouldn't be the case.

Here is my code:

```
var reg = new RegExp('(([AWT]\w\S=)?(\d{0,9}:)?(\d{0,9});)');
var x = $('td').find('.awt')[0].value; 

console.log(x);        // AWT=10:15;
console.log(String(x).match(reg)); // [";", ";", undefined, undefined, "", index: 9, input: "AWT=10:15;", groups: undefined]

       if(String(x).match(reg)){
            console.log("valid");
        }else{
            console.log("Invalid")
        }
```

I was wondering if anyone can help me figure out the right regex for the string.

PS: The string needs to be in that exact format: **(AWT=[0,9]:[0,9];)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `(([AWT]\w\S=)?(\d{0,9}:)?(\d{0,9});)` means:

```
(                       # start group 1
    (                       # start group 2
        [AWT]                   # 1 character A or W or T
        \w                      # 1 word character <=> [A-Za-z0-9_]
        \S                      # 1 non space character
        =                       # equal sign
    )?                      # end group 2, optional
    (                       # start group 3
        \d{0,9}                 # from 0 upto 9 digits
        :                       # colon
    )?                      # end group 3, optional
    (                       # start group 4
        \d{0,9}                 # from 0 upto 9 digits
    )                       # end group 4
    ;                       # semicolon
)                       # end group 1
```

It matches `AWT=10:15;` as well as:

- `blahAWT=123456789:123456789;blah`
- `Wx!=123;`
- `12345;`

Not sure it's what you want!

---

According to your requierement “The string needs to be in that exact format: **AWT=[0,9]:[0,9];**”, this regex will do the job: `^AWT=\d\d:\d\d;$`

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of string
    AWT=        # literally AWT=
    \d\d        # 2 digits
    :           # a colon
    \d\d        # 2 digits
    ;           # a semicolon
$           # end of string
```

Use it this way:

```
var reg = new RegExp('^AWT=\\d\\d:\\d\\d;$');
```

or, better:

```
var reg = /^AWT=\d\d:\d\d;$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape backslashes in the string, or \w becomes w
You need to use ^$ to match on beginning and end, so it only matches if the full string matches

Another option depending on what you are trying to do, is to use negative lookahead `(?!.*)`
or a capture group behind the last `(;.*)` where you would check matches for the final match group for content and reject based on that.

```js
console.log('(([AWT]\w\S=)?(\d{0,9}:)?(\d{0,9});)'); // this is not what you want

function matcher(){
var reg = new RegExp('^(([AWT]\\w\\S=)?(\\d{1,9}:)?(\\d{1,9});)$');
var x = $('td').find('input')[0].value;

console.log(x); // AWT=10:15;
console.log(x.match(reg)); // [";", ";", undefined, undefined, "", index: 9, input: "AWT=10:15;", groups: undefined]

if (reg.test(x)) {
  console.log("valid");
} else {
  console.log("Invalid")
}
}

matcher();
$('td').find('input').on('input',matcher);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr>
<td><input class="awt" value="AWT=10:15;"></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: This works great, however if I test this regex with `AWT=;` it still accepts it. That is supposed to be considered invalid.

Comment: Just change {0,9} to {1,9} so it requires at least one character

Answer (score 0):

@user120242 is totally right about the cause of your bug.

I just want to add another option instead of escaping the characters. If you use `/someRegex/` this is not necessary.

Moreover, if you are always expecting `AWT` at the beginning, this `([AWT]\w\S=)` is not optimal. It means: either A, W or T, then a word character, then a non space character and then =. If it always starts with `AWT=` use `(AWT=)`.

```js
var reg = /(([AWT]\w\S=)?(\d{0,9}:)?(\d{0,9});)/
var x = $('td').find('.awt')[0].value;

console.log(x); // AWT=10:15;
console.log(String(x).match(reg));

if (String(x).match(reg)) {
  console.log("valid");
} else {
  console.log("Invalid")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="awt" value="AWT=10:15;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! However, when I tried `AWT=10:15;;;` or `AWT=10:15;73247` it was still giving me those as a valid string.. I would like the regex to be `AWT=[0-9]:[0-9];`. Anything in the middle besides an int value and anything after the last semi colon should be invalid.